# Android FaceDetector.Face Euler angles are 0 all the time

Tags: android, face-detection, euler-angles

I'm trying to get a the Euler angle of a Face that is detected by FaceDetector.

Here is what I use to output to Logcat:

```
Log.v("debug", " X: " + face.pose(Face.EULER_X) + " Y: " + face.pose(Face.EULER_Y) + " Z: " + face.pose(Face.EULER_Z) );
```

But it always returns 0.0 for all three, no matter what angle the face is at.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you check if there is a detected Face object?

Comment: Do you have a confidence value above CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah the [FaceDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html) from API 1 never returns a pose angle. You can look at the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_external_neven/blob/master/FaceDetector_jni.cpp#L272) to verify.

The newer [FaceDetectionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.FaceDetectionListener.html) from API 14 will return a pose angle, but it's only available on a limited number of devices right now. Not even all devices running API 14 can use it. You have to call [getMaxNumDetectedFaces()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getMaxNumDetectedFaces%28%29) to see if your device supports that API.

You can alternately try using OpenCV. A couple options for that are http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/OpenCV4Android and http://code.google.com/p/javacv/. In my experience they aren't worth the hassle unless you really, really need the pose angle.

Comment: Can I use the FaceDetectionListener to do something simple like detecting faces on the Bitmap (nothing to do with Camera)? And without the pose angle, is there a way for FaceDectector to check for both eyes positions (seems like impossible)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few similar questions here. Check out the first answer from this link:

[Android Facedetector pose values are always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960837/android-facedetector-pose-values-are-always-0)

And see below for someone that says they solved the problem:

[Android Face Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269891/android-face-detection/9272063#9272063)

Answer (score 0):

Set the detector `setMode` to `ACCURATE_MODE`

Here is an example that worked for me in Kotlin:

```
val detector = FaceDetector.Builder(context)
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ACCURATE_MODE)
            .setMode(FaceDetector.ACCURATE_MODE)
            .setTrackingEnabled(true)
            .build()
```

Comment: This question concerned the FaceDetector in API level 1: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html

Answer (score 0):

On the latest version developers needs to set the perfomance mode to PERFORMANCE_MODE_ACCURATE not PERFORMANCE_MODE_FAST

```
setPerformanceMode(FaceDetectorOptions.PERFORMANCE_MODE_ACCURATE)
```