# Android FaceDetector Pose Always Returning Zero

Tags: android, face-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android FaceDetector.Face Euler angles are 0 all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960563/android-facedetector-face-euler-angles-are-0-all-the-time)

I'm working with the Android FaceDetector and seem to have everything working well EXCEPT getting the "Pose" information for a Face. I've tried several different Bitmaps showing faces with varying orientations, but the EULER_X, EULER_Y and EULER_Z always come back as 0. Is there something I'm missing?  Thanks!