# Android Facedetector pose values are always 0

Tags: android

So I'm using androids built in [facedector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html) to detect and determine the position of faces in a bitmap. Right now it works and will tell me: confidence, eyesDistance and midpoint but whenever i try to get the pose it always returns 0 no matter what images i try using.

This is the code I use to get the pose:

```
poseString = "Pose: (" + getFace.pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_X) + ","
                        + getFace.pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_Y) + ","
                        + getFace.pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_Z) + ")";
```

And here is the code I use:

```
arrayFaces = new FaceDetector(picWidth, picHeight, NUM_FACES);
        arrayFaces.findFaces(sourceImage, getAllFaces);

        for (int i = 0; i < getAllFaces.length; i++) {
            getFace = getAllFaces[i];
            try {
                PointF eyesMP = new PointF();
                getFace.getMidPoint(eyesMP);
                poseString = "Pose: ("+ getFace.pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_X) + ","
                        + getFace.pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_Y) + ","
                        + getFace.pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_Z) + ")";
                EULER_X = getFace.EULER_X;
                EULER_Y = getFace.EULER_Y;
                EULER_Z = getFace.EULER_Z;      

                eyesDistance[i] = getFace.eyesDistance();
                eyesMidPts[i] = eyesMP;

                if (DEBUG) {
                    currentx = eyesMidPts[i].x;
                    currenty = eyesMidPts[i].y;
                    betweeneyes = getFace.eyesDistance();

                    Log.d("currentx", currentx + "");
                    Log.d("currenty", currenty + "");
                    Log.d("betweeneyes", betweeneyes + "");
                    Log.d("EULER", "EULER_X: " + EULER_X + "EULER_Y: " + EULER_Y + "EULER_Z: " + EULER_Z);

                    Log.i("Face", i + " " + getFace.confidence() + " "
                            + getFace.eyesDistance() + " " + "Pose: ("
                            + getFace.pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_X) + ","
                            + getFace.pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_Y) + ","
                            + getFace.pose(FaceDetector.Face.EULER_Z) + ")"
                            + "Eyes Midpoint: (" + eyesMidPts[i].x + ","
                            + eyesMidPts[i].y + ")");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    Log.e("Face", i + " is null");
            }




        }
```

Comment: Can we see the code where you're actually using the `FaceDetector`? As far as I can tell from the docs, you should be passing in your own `Face[]` array and then reading directly from those objects.

Comment: check this code as it work for me and other people too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269891/android-face-detection/9272063#9272063

Comment: @Sameer I don't see `Pose` used anywhere in that code.

Answer (score 3):

A cursory google search shows about 10 different posts--some even [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769022/android-facedetector-pose-always-returning-zero)--of people with the same problem. Did you find these? It looks like it might be a bug. I suggest you report it to the [android bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).

**Edit:** You should *definitely* file a bug. Take a look at the face detection source code: [this source file](https://github.com/android/platform_external_neven/blob/master/FaceDetector_jni.cpp#L272) shows that Android will never set these to anything but 0.

Until this changes, there are other CV options for Android. Check out [OpenCV for Android](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android), which is now officially supported by the team.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that, I had looked into OpenCV for Android before but I could never get it set up and actually working, do you know of any good resources?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If you are, have you tried the step-by-step guide that the website I linked you to provides?

Comment: Yes I am, But I see that their website has changed and looks like its been updated since the last time I tried to get it working. I would still like to get the `pose` working with android facedetect since I have all of the other code already working. But I will definitely look into OpenCV for the future.

Comment: See my revised answer, Peter--seems like you're going to have to change your approach if you want euler angles.